# Running Command Line in Java using Runtime.getRuntime()

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, process

I'm creating web application using spring boot, in this web application i need to run a command line using Runtime.getRuntime(), but the problem is that: **this command is executed after the web app** and this is not what i want to do, the question is :

> "*how can i make sure that the Runtime.getRuntime() instruction start
>   when it's called in spring boot application (not at the end of it)"*

the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/toLinPDf")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> convertion(@RequestParam(value = "input", required = false) String in,
        @RequestParam(value = "output", required = false) String out) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    // the methode LinearizePDF contain the command line

    linearizeService.LinearizePDf(in, out);
    logger.warn("call the method linearizeService.LinearizePDf ");
    FileSystemResource result = new FileSystemResource(out);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(result.contentLength())
            .contentType(
                    MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(result.getInputStream())));

}
```

the linearizeService ( contain the method LinearizePDf(in, out)):

```
@Async
public void LinearizePDf(String Input , String Output) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

     // the command line 
     String command = "qpdf --linearize " + Input + "  " + Output;

     Process pr = rt.exec(command );
     logger.warn("run the command");
     pr.destroy();   
}
```

Please, If there's any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quoting the well known site](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

> Simply put – annotating a method of a bean with @Async will make it
>   execute in a separate thread i.e. the caller will not wait for the
>   completion of the called method.

Remove the `@Async` from `LinearizePDf`

In addition, to wait for the completion of the external process you should use `waitFor` and not `destroy`, e.g. `pr.waitFor()`

Comment: Actually what i want to do is: " to run the command line and the java program in the same time " , in my case the command line is executed when the java app finish runnig

Comment: Did you remove the `Async`? It will give you the possibility to return right `ResponseEntity` from the controller

Comment: indeed , i just remove the @Async and i get the same result, it's not working .

Comment: Added `waitFor` - see the answer

Comment: Well i guess @Async is part of the problem you're right so i remove it and put it in the controller and  also FileSystemResource somehow generate a problem : " file [D:\\[Phenix-Monitor]1.pdf] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length " so i remove it and it's working !